# Roboto-Regular font size 14px Issue in windows os

Tags: css, windows, fonts, roboto

Is there an issue with certain characters in Roboto-Regular font , if the font-size is 14px, only for Windows OS? Specially ,the letter 'e' is unclear. When the font was changed to 13px, every letter in this font-family appeared clearly.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try using SVG font in CSS.

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: ‘MyWebFont’;
  src: url(‘webfont.eot’);
  src: url(‘webfont.eot?#iefix’) format(‘embedded-opentype’),
       url(‘webfont.woff’) format(‘woff’),
       url(‘webfont.ttf’) format(‘truetype’),
       url(‘webfont.svg#svgFontName’) format(‘svg’);
 }
```